# Downsides of using Gunicorn with Django for development

Tags: django, gunicorn, development-environment

Gunicorn + Django is a typical combo for production environments. Are there any downsides, apart for the added complexity, of using Gunicorn also for development, instead of runserver?

Comment: I would not use `runserver` for anything except absolute beginner development.

Comment: @JohnGordon Any examples of non "absolute beginner development" for which the built-in dev sever isn't good enough?

Comment: @xyres If you're going to use gunicorn for production, might as well use it in dev from the beginning.  You aren't saving anything by using runserver, and you're setting yourself up to be surprised by the inevitable differences between the two when you do finally switch.

Comment: @JohnGordon That's indeed the reason why I'm asking. If there is no sizeable downside I will stick to it also in dev mode.